# System of equations using metaprogramming

Tags: metaprogramming, julia

I am trying to create a function that computes the residuals of a system of equations using metaprogramming.

This is what I have tried so far (toy example):

```
function syst!(x::Vector, ou::Vector)
    for i in 1:length(x)
        eval(parse("ou[$i] = x[$i]^2 + x[$i]"))
    end
    return ou
end
```

However, when I try to compute the function, Julia says that the variable `x` is not defined. But if I include a `println(parse("ou[$i] = x[$i]^2 + x[$i]"))` I get the code that would be "typed" in the body of the function (sorry if I'm not using the correct technical CS terms, I come from the "scientific culture").

Anyways, it seems that the `parse`ed `x` lives in another scope. How can I bring that parsed `x` to the scope of the function so that it represents the `x` from the arguments of `syst!`?

Bonus: I have a system of 700 equations and they are amenable to be "typed" using metaprogramming, what's the best way/technique to create a function that computes the residuals of the system? Was I on the right track?

Comment: It is in pre-alpha stages, but a new package Dolang.jl is aimed at doing just this. The main API point will be the `make_method` function that takes some Julia expressions, allowed variables, other function parameters, and outputs a function for you. The method I'm referring to is [here](https://github.com/EconForge/dolang/blob/827ee3d200d35709b8e112b90f8703223834bf75/src/compiler.jl#L132-L144)

Comment: Why are you using metaprogramming at all? This example would work if you just take out the `eval(parse("` bit and the corresponding `"))` and remove the `$` symbols.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stefan's comment is right; in this specific example there is no need for metaprogramming. However, if you wanted to generate many lines similar to `ou[i] = x[i]^2 + x[i]` but different in complicated ways, you could generate them with a macro. See http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/manual/metaprogramming/. Macros expand to generated code "in place" as if you had typed it yourself, so variables can refer to the surrounding scope.